# SPARQL Return only IRIs/URIs as result

Tags: sparql, rdf, linked-data

In SPARQL how do I retrieve only IRIs (or URIs) as a result of a BGP?

E.g. in

```
SELECT ?s ?o WHERE 
    {?s ?p ?o }
LIMIT 100
```

Return only those `?o` that are IRIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SPARQL there exist the following tests

> SPARQL tests: isIRI, isURI, isBlank, isLiteral, isNumeric, bound
>
> `isIRI`, `isURI`: returns true if the term is an IRI or a URI
>
> `isBlank`: returns true if the term is a blank node
>
> `isLiteral`: returns true if the term is a literal
>
> `isNumeric`: returns true if the term is a numeric value

Source:[List of SPARQL Filter Functions (Dataworld tutorial)](https://docs.data.world/tutorials/sparql/list-of-sparql-filter-functions.html)

Hence you can write

```
SELECT ?s ?o WHERE {
       ?s ?p ?o 
       FILTER(isIRI(?o)) 
} limit 100
```